# sharing memory allocation with c++ and JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I'm writing a wrapper in Java for a C++ program. The wrapper is done using SWIG. I have the following problem: when I call a function from Java which create a big object in C++, Java doesn't "see" that it has allocated a lot of memory since it's not allocated in Java's heap. The problem is that the garbage collector is not called when the object is deleted as from Java side there is plenty of free memory. What I have tried is to implement what is described here: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_heap_allocations. The idea is to allocate memory space for C++ in Java's heap. As I'm not interested to use that for every `new`, I have renamed the `new` and `delete` and use them explicitly from my C++ code where needed.

This mechanism seems to work (I can see in that Java's heap is growing and shrinked by the garbage collector) but unfortunately I have a random crash whis seems to occur during a `memcpy`.

If I invoke the garbage collector manually my program is working but it's not a very clean method.

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: "Unfortunately, because most Java implementations call malloc and free, this solution will not work for C wrapped structures" have you checked this is not your case?

Comment: Well, you want Java to give you memory from its heap and not GC it until you no longer need the object. How would java know when the latter happens?

Comment: Have a look at the link in my post please, you will see that the `delete` operator call `env->DeleteGlobalRef(pJalloc->ref);
      env->ReleaseByteArrayElements`

Comment: @Viruzzo I'm only using C++ code

Comment: Quite possibly you have bugs in your program. Mixing and matching a variety of allocators sounds like a recipe for strange memcpy bugs.

Comment: If you have a "random crash" when doing this I'd bet that you've got premature garbage collection problems

Comment: Is the crash truly random? Is there a particular memcpy you crash on every time? Also, can u catch the crash in a debugger and print out src, dest values as well as the backtrace from the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact I didn't notice the following line in swig website:

> If you are going to use optimisations turned on with gcc (for example -O2), ensure you also compile with -fno-strict-aliasing

This seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply manually invoke the C++ object destructor via SWIG?  This seems to work for me.